# How to show drawable in NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I want to show a `drawable` icon with a circular background in `NavigationView` i created a circular brown background for a Image but am getting gray circular view as a result  don't know why ? anyone have any idea why it is happening and how to get the desired result ?

drawable code to show icon with circular background, **icon_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#785125"/>
    </shape>
 </item>
 <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:left="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:top="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Result : [image]

But result in `NavigationView` looks like this :

[image]

Comment: why dont u get that icon ?

Comment: @quicklearner that's exactly i want to know i am not getting that icon and that background too. dont know why

Comment: make the center part of your image transparent it will work

Comment: NavigationView items have two stats selected or not selected ... these items are usually grey when they are not selected including the icon and when they are selected they turn into primary color of the app i.e colorPrimary

Comment: hi, i think your image size is too long try with short size..

Comment: Use this custom library, easy to implement. You can also able to implement the `Drawable` icon too. https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Comment: What if your icon `tint`, `backgroundTint` property may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the issue and the solution so posting the solution it may will help someone for drawable i reduce margin :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#785125"/>
  </shape>
  </item>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"/>
  </layer-list>
```

and in java code making icon tint as null works

```
  navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Comment: this should be the answer, i used `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` too, it solved my problem